# installing python modules ImportError (dlib, imutils) raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspbian, dlib

I am trying to install dlib on my raspberry py for a computer vision project with opencv. I installed successfully opencv, and I can import cv2 module in python.

```
    $ python
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'
>>>
```

Then I installed 2 modules with pip install: dlib and imutils. I can see them in pip freeze:

```
$ pip freeze | grep dlib
dlib==19.10.0
$ pip freeze | grep imutils
imutils==0.4.6
```

But the problem is that in python i can't import them, python does not find them and I can't use them.

```
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dlib
>>> import imutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named imutils
```

How can I fix this problem?

Edit:
@hoefling

```
$ python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))"

/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0

$ pip -V
pip 10.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Comment: Run `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))"`. It will print a list of paths. Then run `pip -V` and check if the printed path is in the above list. If it's not, you have multiple python versions installed and are using `pip` for the wrong python version.

Comment: @hoefling what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system has `pip` symlinked to `pip3`, so when you use `pip`, it installs packages for `python3`. Use the `pip2` to target `pip` for `python2`:

```
$ pip2 install dlib imutils
```

It may be the case that you don't have `pip` installed for `python2`. In this case, you have to install it separately. Judging by `dist-packages` in the `sys.path`, you have a debian or some derivative, so most probably you'll have to `apt install python2-pip` to add `pip2` to the system.

Comment: I did what you said but it still does not work. I have the same output for >>> import dlib. => ImportError: No module named dlib

Comment: @DanielC what does `pip2 -V` return?

Comment: `$ pip2 -V`  -->
`pip 10.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

Comment: Ok, now check what location `dlib` was installed into: `pip show dlib | grep Location`. It should be one of the locations in `sys.path` for the import to work properly.

Comment: `$ pip show dlib | grep Location` -->
`Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`

Comment: Oops, I meant `pip2`: `pip2 show dlib | grep Location`.

Comment: `pip2 show dlib | grep Location` does not show anything

Comment: So it's not installed - did you actually follow the steps in my answer? `pip2 install dlib imutils`, most probably you need to prepend it with `sudo`.

Comment: I gave the command `$ pip2 install dlib imutils` 3 times and every time it was installed again. strange. now I'm trying with `sudo` and waiting to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

I installed imutils with

```
sudo pip install imutils --target /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

into the python 3.5 folder and everything went right

Answer (score 0):

Like hoefling said in the comments, you may have multiple python versions installed because the Rpi comes with both 2 and 3.  If you are using Python 3, use pip3 instead of pip.